# Error in MySQL/PHP real_escape_string UPDATE function

Tags: php, google-maps

```
   $query = sprintf("UPDATE populationgender SET male='%s', female = '%s' WHERE popgenderid='4'",
             mysql_real_escape_string($male),
             mysql_real_escape_string($female));
```

Is this a valid sprintf code? because when i use this it does nothing hehe it is connected via googlemaps btw :) pls help thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, this is way too much code. Please try to isolate the problem and tell us what exactly goes wrong where

Answer (score 0):

You have used escape in javascript as well as php. 
Try using escape in javascript and unescape in php.

`$myvar = urldecode($_GET["male"]);`

this will work